# Service not run

Tags: android, service

I have try to use service in android

activity -> in position login

```
public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
        if (userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())) {
            setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

            startService(new Intent(this, CountDownTimer.class));


        } else {
            // user is not logged in show login screen
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
            // Closing dashboard screen
            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

Service class

```
public class CountDownTimer extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats! MyService Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("TAG", "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("TAG", "onStart");    
    }

     @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "MyService Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d("TAG", "onDestroy");
        }

}
```

I have add this service in android manifest

i don't understand what wrong with the code, i try more tutorial but same the service not run. please help

Comment: please show your mainfest.xml, maybe here is something wrong by adding service

Comment: Check your packages in your AndroidManifest and see if your code is coming to the start service. You can do it my doing Log just before the start line

Comment: How do you know your service isn't running? Just because you don't see **Toasts** from a Service, doesn't mean it isn't running. This isn't a reliable debugging mechanism. Set breakpoints in a debugger or use `Log` messages and check the logcat on the emulator or device.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have declared you service in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".CountDownTimer" />
```

Stopping the Service where ever you want

```
 stopService(new Intent(this,CountDownTimer.class));
```

If the above is correctly filled. Then please make sure to remove `Toast`

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Congrats! MyService Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

A service cannot show you `Toast` with using `this`. Because `this` contain information about service.

Hence try `Log` to confirm your service status. Plus make sure that your service is not already running.
Hence `stop` the service and then `start` again.

Comment: he said he has added the service in manifest, maybe he should show HOW he has added it...

Comment: i have added in manifest same like MDMalik, i don't understand why service not run i have try and try some tutorial but same not run

Comment: @user2486312 Do a Log.i("Something", "something"); just before ` startService(new Intent(this, CountDownTimer.class));`. Just to give you an idea

Comment: @user2486312 remove Toast from your service. You need to have to see your LogCat to get Idea.....

Comment: it's same i remove toast still no run, i try log Log.i("Something", "something"); before startservice this read in logcat

Comment: try stopping your service first and then starting it. at the end  if it does not work. then its the androidmanifest. don't write .CountDownTimer . Write it with complete package name.CountDownTimer